# Create wallet & send tokens for Stellar-based token

Tags: token, token-wallet

I have created a non-XLM token on the Stellar Network. I can make an offer for it on StellarTerm, but what I want to do is send the token to another public key.

At https://www.stellar.org/account-viewer/ when I log in with my distributing account's secret key, I see my token and my Lumens but I only see the option to send Lumens.

How to send my token directly to a public XLM address, and how to create a wallet for the non-XLM token? I looked in the docs and didn't see anything and only see XLM wallets on the site.

Comment: Not sure exactly. But probably you have to create a trustlines. See [trustlines](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/assets.html#trustlines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stellar account viewer only allows sending XLM.

You can click on any of the wallets here:
https://www.stellar.org/lumens/wallets/
And see which ones mention "Multiple Assets"

I personally use the stellar desktop app.

In addition, there are web services that allow you to send assets, for example:
https://stellardesk.org
https://mystellar.tools (this one is not open source, so use your own judgment when entering your seed into it)